# Proportional venn diagram for more than 3 sets

Tags: python, matlab, plot, matplotlib

I have a collection of documents in MongoDB where each has one or more categories in a list. Using map reduce, I can get the details of how many documents have each unique combination of categories:

```
['cat1']               = 523
['cat2']               = 231
['cat3']               = 102
['cat4']               = 72
['cat1','cat2']        = 710
['cat1','cat3']        = 891
['cat1','cat3','cat4'] = 621 ...
```

where the totals are for the number of documents that exact combination of categories.

I'm looking for a sensible way to present this data, and I think a venn diagram with proportional areas would be a good idea. Using the above example, the area cat1 would be 523+710+891+621, the area of the overlap between cat1 and cat3 would be 891+621, the area of overlap between cat1, cat3, cat4 would be 621 etc.

Does anyone have any tips for how I might go about implementing this? I'd preferably like to do it in Python (+Numpy/MatPlotLib) or MatLab.

Comment: Given that a Venn diagram will not do it (see comment by ninjagecko below), and since alternatives are being suggested (see fraxel idea), I thought I would try an alternative myself, a network graph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Problem

We need to represent counts of multiple interconnected categories of object, and a Venn diagram would be unable to represent more than a trivial amount of categories and their overlap.

### A Solution

Consider each of the categories and their combinations as a node in a graph. Draw the graph such that the size of the node represents the count in each category, and the edges connect the related categories. The advantage of this approach is: multiple categories can be accommodated with ease, and this becomes a type of connected bubble chart.

### The Result

[image: network layout]

### The Code

The proposed solution uses [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) to create the data structure and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) to draw it. If data is presented in the right format, this will scale to a large number of categories with multiple connections.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def load_nodes():
    text = '''  Node    Size
                1        523
                2        231
                3        102
                4         72
                1+2      710
                1+3      891
                1+3+4    621'''
    # load nodes into list, discard header
    # this may be replaced by some appropriate output 
    # from your program
    data = text.split('\n')[1:]
    data = [ d.split() for d in data ]
    data = [ tuple([ d[0], 
                    dict( size=int(d[1]) ) 
                    ]) for d in data]
    return data

def load_edges():
    text = '''  From   To
                1+2    1
                1+2    2
                1+3    1
                1+3    3
                1+3+4    1
                1+3+4    3
                1+3+4    4'''
    # load edges into list, discard header
    # this may be replaced by some appropriate output 
    # from your program
    data = text.split('\n')[1:]
    data = [ tuple( d.split() ) for d in data ]
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scale_factor = 5
    G = nx.Graph()
    nodes = load_nodes()
    node_sizes = [ n[1]['size']*scale_factor
                  for n in nodes ]

    edges = load_edges()
    G.add_edges_from( edges )

    nx.draw_networkx(G, 
                     pos=nx.spring_layout(G),
                     node_size = node_sizes)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

### Other Solutions

Other solutions might include: [bubble charts](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bubble.html), [Voronoi diagrams](http://www.christophermanning.org/projects/voronoi-diagram-with-force-directed-nodes-and-delaunay-links/), [chord diagrams](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/chord.html), and [hive plots](http://www.hiveplot.net/) among others. None of the linked examples use Python; they are just given for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the great ideas and alternatives. I think this network graph idea by gauden is the most suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 6):

I believe ninjagecko is correct and this cannot generally be represented as a diagram of intersections, unless you don't mind the diagram being in n dimensions. However, it can be represented in 2D if you have a diagram for each category showing all its intersections - and this itself can be a single diagram. So this may be a more appropriate way to represent your data. I've produced a stacked barchart to illustrate:

[image]

The code:

```
cats = ['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4']
data = {('cat1',): 523, ('cat2',): 231, ('cat3',): 102, ('cat4',): 72, ('cat1','cat2'): 710,('cat1','cat3'): 891,('cat1','cat3','cat4') : 621}

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import random

colors = dict([(k,(random(),random(),random())) for k in data.keys()])
print colors
for i, cat in enumerate(sorted(cats)):
    y = 0
    for key, val in data.items():
        if cat in key:
            plt.bar(i, val, bottom=y, color=colors[key])
            plt.text(i,y,' '.join(key))
            y += val
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(cats))+0.4, sorted(cats))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is **impossible in general** unless, roughly, the graph of intersections is a [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) *AND* you have no 4-way intersections. There is also a limit on edge lengths (unless you are willing to draw amorphous blobs to represent area); so if you insist on drawing circles, this is even **more** restricted.

In very simple cases, you can make a routine to draw a 3-way Venn diagram, then "add" another circle on "the other side" of the triplet. In the above case, `1,3,4` is that triplet, and `2` is the odd-one-out.

If it *is* possible because your data satisfies the above conditions (for some reason your graph is planar and extremely complicated), *AND* you use amorphous blobs, you can draw the planar graph, and slowly grow each edge to "balloon up" into an ellipsoid. You can do this in a relaxative manner: they balloon up if their intersections are lower than what they should be, and shrink if their intersections are higher than what they should be. (They actually have 2 dimensions to do this in: fattening and elongating; pick as appropriate. Elongating will push the rest of the graph, so you will have to check that this does not make things impossible, e.g. by using a physical spring-based layout.) Eventually you will probably converge on an answer, which you will have to check for accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

How about a variation on Gauden's answer? Each category is a node, and weighted edges between the nodes represent the degree overlap. The more overlap, the thicker the edge.

Answer (score 1):

See [some examples of higher-order diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Edwards.27_Venn_diagrams).

I don't know how you'd go about scaling for proportional areas, though.

Maybe if you took a graph of the appropriate order and tesselated it. Then you could assign desired areas to each triangle and do some sort of pressure-diffusion, allowing the vertices to shift and maybe allowing some pressure to "leak" from each triangle to a neighbor belonging to the same set?