# Connected bubble chart in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have the following:

```
type <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a&b', 'a&c', 'b&c', 'a&b&c')
distribution <- c(.25, .1, .12, .18, .15, .05, .15)
```

I would like to create a bubble chart like the one shown in the selected answer to this question:
[Proportional venn diagram for more than 3 sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804432/proportional-venn-diagram-for-more-than-3-sets) where the bubble areas are proportional to the values in the distribution vector and the connecting lines show the relationship between the 3 main bubbles 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

Comment: Package requests are generally considered off topic. It would be better to include a small [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of some data you have that you would like to visualize in this way and rephrase your question.

Comment: `igraph` package could be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `igraph` library with your data, you could create edges and vertices to represent your desired plot. Here's one way to do it

```
library(igraph)
type <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a&b', 'a&c', 'b&c', 'a&b&c')
distribution <- c(.25, .1, .12, .18, .15, .05, .15)

mx <- strsplit(type,"&")
ei <- sapply(mx,length)>1
cx <- do.call(rbind, mapply(cbind, type[ei], mx[ei]))

gg <- graph.edgelist(cx, directed=FALSE)    

V(gg)[type]$size<-distribution *200
plot(gg)
```

And this is the plot I got

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of the vertex perimeter? `list.vertex.attributes(gg)` returns "name" "size" "color". However, modifying the "color" attribute only changes the fill.

Comment: Try `V(gg)[type]$frame.color<-"darkgreen"`