# Making a list of lists into a Venn Diagram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, venn-diagram

I manipulated a pandas data frame in a way such that I have created a list of lists. For the sake of simplicity lets pretend it is a list of list of numbers (in reality they are strings).

I would like to create some sort of visualisation preferably a venn diagram which shows me the overlap between lists. In other words some of the list are subsets of others etc.

for example if the list of lists was

```
 a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[8,9],[6,7],[5,6]]
```

this list would return a a venn diagram with one circle within a circle. one circle intersecting that larger circle. and one circle completely alone.

I have tried to use matplotlib_venn but to little avail
any ideas on how i should proceed?

Comment: The problem is that matplotlib_venn can only handle up to 3 sets at a time and it [doesn't look like](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/issues/15) they'll be extending it any time soon.  Have you considered [other visualizations for your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804432/proportional-venn-diagram-for-more-than-3-sets) or maybe switching languages and using [VennDiagram](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/library-to-generate-a-scaled-4-set-venn-diagram) in R (if you don't have to stick with python), though there are some issues with scaling.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I will try and find another way to visualise it. The issue is that the list of lists is made up 400 lists. I don't think it is feasible to create them manually.