# Plot Venn diagram with four set using Matlab

Tags: matlab, venn-diagram

I was looking for a matlab script to plot a venn diagram for four sets of elements but in vain. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: There's no Venn diagram functionality natively in MATLAB, but there are several user contributions available on the File Exchange. One is [venn](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22282-venn?focused=5178911&tab=function). I've never used it so can't vouch for its functionality.

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: [Proportional venn diagram for more than 3 sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10804432/52738)

Answer (score 0):

When you need to find usefull matlab functions a great place and comunnity to visit is https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/ it is a great community that shares many interesting matlab things. In this case there is  https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22282-venn?focused=5178911&tab=function (suggested in a comment by @Phil Goddard) which you can use as a normal dot m file:

```
venn([3,4,5], [1 2 1 2])
```

[image]

you should take a look at venn.m for additional options, descriptions, references, and examples.

Comment: venn.m is great but it doesn't support more than 3 sets